# Excel 2010 VBA Error 1004 with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have this code:

```
Dim fStrecke As String
fStrecke = "=A" & z & "*B" & z & "*C" & z
wks.Cells(z, "L").Formula = fStrecke

Dim fZeit As String
fZeit = "=IF(ISBLANK(H" & z & ");((A" & z & "*B" & z & "*I" & z & ")-I" & z & ")+(A" & z & "*B" & z & "*J" & z & ");(A" & z & "*B" & z & "*H" & z & "))"
wks.Cells(z, "K").Formula = fZeit
```

The first formula is working and for the second i get an runtime error 1004. any idea? i have formatted the column K as user defined with "m:ss".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two options for you:

1. use `.FormulaLocal` property: `wks.Cells(z, "K").FormulaLocal = fZeit`
2. use comma `,` as separator instead of semicolon `;` (even if your local settings require `;` as standard separator):

---

```
fZeit = "=IF(ISBLANK(H" & z & "),((A" & z & "*B" & z & "*I" & z & ")-I" & z & ")+(A" & z & "*B" & z & "*J" & z & "),(A" & z & "*B" & z & "*H" & z & "))"
wks.Cells(z, "K").Formula = fZeit
```

Comment: What a joke! I've been looking for this solution for quite a time .. The separator from my local settings is `;` so that's what I used in my code..